# Which button was clicked without using Javascript?

Tags: html, ruby

There is a html code

```
<form>
  <button type="submit" name="button-name" value="btn1">button1</button>
  <button type="submit" name="button-name" value="btn2">button2</button>
</form>
```

Is there any way to determine which button was clicked on a server side? I'd like not to use javascript and not to replace them with `input`.

That's funny but I have `nil` in `params["button-name"]`

Comment: change the name attribute?

Comment: You can just check the value of button-name server-side. If its value is btn1, you clicked button one.

Comment: That's funny but I have nil in params["button-name"].

Comment: What language are you using? Do you have a way to check POST or GET data?

Comment: How about telling us what server side technology you are using? People are guessing in their answers and may be wrong.

Comment: Unless `params` contains both `GET` and `POST` values `params["button-name"]` will be `nil` - `form` defaults to `GET` not `POST`.  Add `method="post"` to your `form` tag and try again :-)

Comment: What type of server side code are you running?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would work if you are working with PHP on the server side.

```
if(isset($_GET['button-name']))
    echo $_GET['button-name'];
```

Comment: Only if OP is using PHP. The above will not compile with ASP.NET.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to check the value of the `button-name` parameter on the server side to determine which button was clicked.  In decent browsers it will be the value of the value attribute, but in IE you will receive the inner html of each button.

So for example, if I clicked the first button and was using Java on the server side:

In IE

```
String param = reqeust.getParameter("button-name");
System.out.println(param); // Prints button1
```

In Firefox

```
String param = reqeust.getParameter("button-name");
System.out.println(param); // Prints btn1
```

Answer (score 1):

If you were to use PHP, this would work (assuming you use GET instead of POST):

if((isset($_GET['button-name'])) && ($_GET['button-name'] === 'btn1' ||  $_GET['button-name'] === 'btn2')){

}